# TextFileParser and double-quotes in the middle of text

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have a csv file that I am importing and every once in awhile the product description contains some quotes in the middle that cause the TextFileParser to stop.  The line where it is failing is this:

> 42000168,1004,10035,423,"1000 LB 3/8" DCD ORG", "HALB WIP",0

You can see the product code has 3/8" in the middle of the beginning and ending quotation.  However - this CSV comes from an SAP system where they are not going to adjust the product names.

My Code:

```
Dim parser as TextFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(csvFile)
parser.TextFeldType = FieldType.Delimited
parser.Delimiters = new String() {","}
parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

While Not parser.EndOfData
    Dim fields as string() = parser.ReadFields()
    Dim row as DataRow = rawTable.NewRow()
    row("MTL") = fields(0)
    row("PL") = fields(1)
    row("MG") = fields(2)
    row("MRP") = fields(3)
    row("MTLDESC") = fields(4)
    row("GPDESC") = fields(5)      
    row("NET") = fields(6) 

    rawTable.Rows.Add(row)
End While
```

How can I make it so that this type of Product description works when using the parser?

Comment: This is clearly invalid csv data. I'd look to _fix it_ (because it really is _broken) on the other end that created the csv in the first place. Note I'm NOT suggesting changing any product names. I am suggesting fixing the broken export code so the value is escaped properly.

Comment: That isn't possible.  These are legacy product names that are in SAP.  This file used to be parsed no problem with SQL SSIS, btw.  I know it is invalid, but I have to figure out some sort of work-around.

Comment: Again: not suggesting to change the names. But the processes that exports those names should detect and escape the double quote character, and for it not to do that is a **broken** export. Your other options are pre-processing the broken data yourself (this could get painful) or using a different csv parser. There are several on NuGet; perhaps one is more forgiving.

Comment: I do understand that the export should be correct.  I also know there is no way in hell they will do it :)  I will have a look at NuGet and see what I can find for now.  thank you.

Comment: If you don't need to import cases like `this,"abc",is quoted` you could "escape" the `3/8"` case and similar by initially replacing every quote **not** having a comma in front with a different character, then import line, then reverse. Example: `123,"Size 3/8" bolt", 999`  with `123,"Size 3/8§ bolt", 999`  etc.  Alternatively find a separator different from quote, like pipe, tab or `¤`. Many ways around, but *never* guaranteed not to break on niche cases.

Comment: You could try with [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). In its configuration, you can specify a [Mode property](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvMode.cs) that defines the way quotes in Fields are handled

Comment: Do the troublesome double-quotes always appear in predictable places, like 3/8" ? If so, you could replace `3/8"` with `3/8""`, etc., maybe by reading the file into a string/stringbuilder, doing the replacement, and feeding it to the TextFieldParser via a [StringReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader).